# Move folder to other folder programmed by ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

When I moved ASP.NET MVC 5 project folder from `D:\EAMser\EAMser\EAMser` to `E:\EAMser`, the views are not properly linked with their respective controllers.

When I compile the page, the URL generated is incorrect, such as `https://localhost:44312/Views/Home/About.cshtml`. When I correct it in the explorer link to `https://localhost:44312/Home/About`, it works.

When I go to view About and click right-click, I can not show go to controller.

How I can resolve this problems?

Thank you for helping me.